# How to notify viewmodel collection that property on model class has changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, checkbox

I have a class that has a boolean property called `IsChecked`. 
A collection of this class exist in my viewmodel. I've bound a datagrid in my view to this collection. I need to call a method in my viewmodel when the checkbox in the view gets changed. I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class and it is firing when I check the box but I don't know how to call the method in my viewmodel.

Here's the class in my model...

```
public class AccountComponent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the collection in my viewmodel...

```
    private ObservableCollection<AccountComponent> _accountComponents;
    private string _accountStatus;

    public ObservableCollection<AccountComponent> AccountComponents
    {
        get { return _accountComponents; }
        set
        {
            _accountComponents = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountComponents");
            CalculateComponentTotal();
        }
    }
```

Here's my XAML in the view...

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AccountComponents}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Component" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextBlock-Sketch}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Amount,StringFormat={}{0:C}}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Charge" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextBlock-Sketch}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `AccountComponent` implements INPC you can observe the `IsChecked` property in your VM.

say in your VM constructor:

```
AccountComponents = new ObservableCollection<AccountComponent>();
AccountComponents.CollectionChanged += AccountComponentsOnCollectionChanged;

...

private void AccountComponentsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.NewItems != null && args.NewItems.Count != 0)
    foreach (AccountComponent account in args.NewItems)
      account.PropertyChanged += AccountOnPropertyChanged;

  if (args.OldItems != null && args.OldItems.Count != 0)
    foreach (AccountComponent account in args.OldItems)
      account.PropertyChanged -= AccountOnPropertyChanged;
}

private void AccountOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
    // Invoke Your VM Function Here
}
```

That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

In Xaml:
add the following namspace..

```
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Now for you checkbox add the following code:

```
    <CheckBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>
```

In ViewModel:

```
 public ICommand CheckedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(OnChecked);//Delegate command is the Implemntation of Icommand Interface
        }
    }

public void OnLogin(object param)
    {
        //code for you checked event
    }
```

Hope this will help you.